# postgresql 9.5 - tracking changes to a value over time

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'd like to track the price of an item on a website over time in a nice way. One option would be to just have a table like

```
create table prices (
     name text,
     price decimal,
     updated timestamp
)
```

and every time I update the prices just create a new row in this table.
However, I think this approach is not very 'nice' in my situation, for the following reasons:

1. I am keeping track of several 1000 items at any given time,
2. I am updating prices every 5 or so minutes, and
3. The prices typically don't change very often, and sometimes don't change at all.

Because of these reasons, for a particular item, say, `dove bodywash`, my prices table could contain 200 rows that all look like

```
'dove soap' | 3.00 | <a new timestamp every 5 minutes>
```

Which seems a bit ridiculous. 
A much nicer solution, in my opinion, would be to add an additional `price_history` table which stores a time range during which an item had a particular price. For example, `price_history` might have columns

```
name | price | created_at | updated_at
```

and the desired behaviour would be that whenever I update the price of  `dove soap`, there would be a trigger that automatically checks to see if the price has changed - if it hasn't, then just change the `updated_at` of the corresponding entry in prices_history, and if it has, then create a new row in prices_history for the new price. As an example of the execution I'd like to have:

1) at time1 I do `insert into prices ('dove soap', 3.00)`. At this point, the price_history table would contain a row

```
|'dove soap' | 3.00 | time1 | null |
```

2) at time2 I do `update prices set price = 3.00 where name = 'dove soap'`. Now the price_history table looks like

```
'dove soap' | 3.00 | time1 | time2
```

3) at time3 the price is still 3.00. price_history should look like

```
'dove soap' | 3.00 | time1| time3
```

4) at time4 the price is 3.50. price_history should now look like:

```
'dove soap' | 3.00 | time1 | time3 
'dove soap' | 3.50 | time4 | null
```

My problems are

1. I'm not sure if this is a good way to go about this, and
2. I'm not 100% sure what a good way to implement this would be.

Any advice on either point above is much appreciated!

Thanks :-)

Edit: I should include that one thing I looked at was the `temporal_tables` postgresql extension, which uses a similar prices/ price_history/ set up. The problem with it is that it seemed like it would create a new row in the price_history table every time the price was updated, event if it hadn't changed, which defeats the purpose. It seems to me that there isn't a way to modify this default behaviour, but if anyone knows better please let me know!

Comment: I have a similar situation. Each of my records has a start date and an end date. Whenever a record is added (with a new start date), a trigger fires to update the end date of the previous record with the appropriate date. In your case I'd add a trigger before insert that doesn't insert if the price is the same. Wouldn't bother changing updated_at if nothing has changed. Finally, I'd have what you call price_history as your only table and a view extracting the current records.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you by any chance have a link to an example of creating such a trigger? I'm fairly new to sql and don't have a great understanding of how things work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a design that could work, using one table and a view... I make a couple of assumptions, namely that you don't really care about tracking the last update time (but see below), and that the end time for the newest entry is 2999-12-31 23:59:59. (You could leave it blank, but I don't like null values and having a date in there means you can do between queries...).

Create the price_history_table:

```
create table price_history(

article_id integer, -- I like using article ids
article_name text,  -- I don't like using reserved words for columns
price decimal not null,
start_time timestamp not null,
end_time timestamp not null default '2999-12-31 23:59:59')
```

(If you don't want to use an article_id, replace article_id with article_name throughout below, although you might consider storing your item descriptions in a separate table and storing only the id in the "big" table. Takes less space on the disk and one fewer column to write).

Create a unique constraint on the article_id and end time:

```
alter table price_history add constraint article_id_end_time unique  (article_id,end_time)
```

... and a primary key on article_id and start_time

```
alter table price_history add constraint pk_price_history primary key (article_id,start_time);
```

I think it's important to have these constraints to prevent you entering garbage into the table, since duplicate times would break your logic.

Now the trigger function. The trigger does nothing if the price hasn't changed, otherwise it updates the end_time of the last record to the new start_time.

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_enddate()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100.0
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $BODY$

BEGIN



    if EXISTS (select * from price_history where article_id = NEW.article_id AND end_time ='2999-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp AND price = NEW.price) THEN
    -- the price hasn't changed, don't do anything

    RETURN NULL;

    ELSE --Set the end date to the new startdate
            update price_history set end_time = NEW.start_time where article_id = new.article_id AND end_time ='2999-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp;
         RETURN NEW;   
    END IF;



    END;

$BODY$;
```

And the trigger itself.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_enddate BEFORE INSERT on price_history FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_enddate();
```

And a view for the most recent records.

```
 CREATE VIEW prices AS
   SELECT article_id,article_name,price,start_time from price_history where end_time  ='2999-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp;
```

If you want to find out whether a price changed for a given update you can try things like

```
SELECT * from price_history where start_time <= mytime and end_time > mytime;
```

Note that you need to be a bit careful with "between" queries because they include the start and end points and you could get a duplicate if your time happens to match a start_time.

The start_time equates to the time the price last changed. You could store the update times in a different table and simply join on start_time <= update_time and end_time > update_time to get you a "full history".

Not sure about the performance with the indexes if you're constantly adding records, so you might get better performance if you don't have the indexes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fully fleshed out response, it is extremely helpful. I *do* need to keep track of the last updated time, unfortunately. I saw your comment at the end regarding that... but could I also just modify the trigger function to do an update to the existing row in the first case of the if / else?

Comment: You could do, but you need to think carefully about exactly how things are going to work... E.g. you might want a third column last_updated and, yes, you could modify the trigger (SELECT NEW.update_time = now() )